# Crop image with react-avatar-edit library and send with Formik value in react

Tags: reactjs, formik

How can I send the user information to the server along with the avatar photo?
I prefer to send together.
I use the following two libraries:
1: react-avatar-edit
2: Formik

I have a problem on the Nodejs server side to save?
Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `FormData` object and append all your form fields in addition to the `avatar` field in the `onSubmit` function.

```
  ...
  const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState(null);
  function onSubmit(values) {
    const formData = new FormData();
    
    formData.append("avatar", avatar);
    formData.append("username", values.username);


    fetch("/endpoint", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    })
    .then((response) => {
      // ...
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // ...
    });
  }
```

You may iterate over the `values` object and append them all by doing `Object.keys(values)`

```
Object.keys(values).forEach((key) => {
    if (key === "avatar") {
      formData.append(key, avatar);
    } else {
      formData.append(key, values[key]);
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you brother, my question is solved.